Reverse engineering locks?
I had some questions regarding reverse engineering locks (physical locks/pin tumblers etc). I'm not sure if they'd qualify as questions here though. Any thoughts from anyone?

I'd think this is perfectly on-topic as per the FAQ. Relevant entry:

hardware analysis and testing

There is not much more to be said. Locks are hardware just like other consumer hardware. We cannot suddenly say it is less hardware than PCBs if this wasn't explicitly ruled out in the first place.
However, you may want to help out on Area51. There is a proposal (just noticed you also commented on that yourself on Ange's answer).

I personally like lock-picking and brainteasers, which are interesting 'physical' forms of reverse engineering, however I'm also feeling it's too different to fit in - it probably requires its own forum.

I'm part of the lock-picking proposal on area51, however i've not seen much momentum behind it. Its potentially more ontopic on sec.se since there is a physical-sec tag, its just that generally speaking, my question was more geared towards reversing the workings of a lock rather than picking it itself.

@D3C4FF I think that questions that relate to say understanding the mechanism or REing the mechanism would be fine. We also have [tag:hardware] :)

@Ange This site is RE and not RCE even though the questions dont reflect it at the moment. We should try to ask/accept more hardware questions :)

@AshRj when i think of hardware I think more like IC's, CPUs etc.
